# Using gridview kartik

Tags: gridview, yii2

I want to change default gridview in yii2 project. So, I install gridview from kartik using composer. I use this:

$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-grid "@dev"

But there is an error when I use it. The error tell me that I don't configure the kartik\grid\Module. So, I configure it in commom\config\main.php, this is the code:

```
'modules' => [
    'auth' => [
         'class' => 'common\modules\auth\Module',
    ],
    'gridview' => [
         'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
    ],
],
```

But then there is an error again. The error is :

The class '\kartik\mpdf\Pdf' was not found and is required for PDF export functionality....

So, what's the problem? Can I use kartik\grid\GridView without pdf?

This is the new gridview code:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'idPolling',
            'namaPolling',
            'statusPolling',
            'tanggalBuka',
            'tanggalTutup',

            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: set `'export' => false,`. https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/155

Comment: Where is I set it?

Answer (score 1):

set export false like this

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'export'=>false,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'idPolling',
            'namaPolling',
            'statusPolling',
            'tanggalBuka',
            'tanggalTutup',

            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```